# JavaScript Error: Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I created DropDownList with checkboxes
There was an error in js:

```
document.onclick = check;
function check(e) {
    var target = (e && e.target) || (event && event.srcElement);
    var obj = document.getElementById('divChkList');
    var obj1 = document.getElementById('ddlChkList');
    if (target.id != "alst" && !target.id.match("chkLstItem")) {
        if (!(target == obj || target == obj1)) {
            obj.style.display = 'none'
        }
```

html :

```
<table>
      <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="width: 165px">
                  <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phDDLCHK" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                  <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Get Checked" OnClick="btn_Click" />
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblSelectedItem" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
      </tr>
</table>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidList" runat="server" />
```

Here is the code cs in Page_load
Here I've defined dropdownlist:

```
 DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
        ddl.ID = "ddlChkList";
        ListItem lstItem = new ListItem();
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, lstItem);
        ddl.Width = new Unit(155);
        ddl.Attributes.Add("onmousedown", "showdivonClick()");
        CheckBoxList chkBxLst = new CheckBoxList();
        chkBxLst.ID = "chkLstItem";
        chkBxLst.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "showdiv()");
        DataTable dtListItem = GetListItem();
        int rowNo = dtListItem.Rows.Count;
        string lstValue = string.Empty;
        string lstID = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < rowNo - 1; i++)
        {
            lstValue = dtListItem.Rows[i]["Value"].ToString();
            lstID = dtListItem.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString();
            lstItem = new ListItem("<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" id=\"alst\" style=\"text-decoration:none;color:Black; \" onclick=\"getSelectedItem(' " + lstValue + "','" + i + "','" + lstID + "','anchor');\">" + lstValue + "</a>", dtListItem.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString());
            lstItem.Attributes.Add("onclick", "getSelectedItem('" + lstValue + "','" + i + "','" + lstID + "','listItem');");
            chkBxLst.Items.Add(lstItem);
        }
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
        div.ID = "divChkList";
        div.Controls.Add(chkBxLst);
        div.Style.Add("border", "black 1px solid");
        div.Style.Add("width", "160px");
        div.Style.Add("height", "180px");
        div.Style.Add("overflow", "AUTO");
        div.Style.Add("display", "none");
        phDDLCHK.Controls.Add(ddl);
        phDDLCHK.Controls.Add(div);
```

The error here `obj.style.display = 'none'`

I have been looking online for a fix and nothing is working?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: post your HTML.

Comment: Are you sure `divChkList` is defined?

Comment: it means that javascript can't locate divChkList. I agree that you should post your html

Comment: In your html `divChkList` and `ddlChkList` is nowhere to be found. That is why you're getting the error

Comment: in the piece of html you posted there is no element with the id `divChkList` nor `ddlChkList` nor `chkLstItem`.

Answer (score 2):

HMTL provided in the question does not have an element with ID `divChkList`

Even if it existed, The correct way of calling an ASP.net control would be like this

```
var obj = document.getElementById('<%=divChkList.ClientID%>');
```

This is because asp.net does not render the same id you specify in the markup of a `server control` , unless to specify to keep it static.